# How to pass single variable from Jquery to PHP and access it in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Not able to access the value passed from Jquery to PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Doesn't load the PHP file? Doesn't fire the callback?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$.get( 'js_test.php?b='+b,function(data) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is an object, not an array. Elements in it need a *key* and a *value*. Try this:

```
b = a.text();
if (b != '') {  
   $.get('js_test.php',{'b': b}, function(data) { });
}
```

I've included the quotes for clarity, but in fact you can just write:

```
b = a.text();
if (b != '') {  
   $.get('js_test.php', {b: b}, function(data) { });
}
```

The first `b` is the name of the variable that'll be used in your PHP code; the second `b` is the Javascript variable, and will get replaced with the right value. A piece of code that more clearly demonstrates this happening might be:

```
if (a.text() != '') {  
   $.get('js_test.php', {b: a.text()}, function(data) { });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, for your clear explaination.. Jquery is fine now. I am trying to access it in PHP using the below code and it does,n't seem to do anything. I have PHP, Jquery and HTML in the same file(js_test.php).   if($_GET['b'] != "") 
{
 echo "hello";
 $Total_Calculated_Cash = b;
 echo b;
}

Comment: @user679460: Sounds like this is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either by passing it as a uri item in a HTTP GET request (like your attempting to do) or by using ajax/post and posting data to a awaiting .php file (HTTP POST).

To use the GET request (In Response to above) you could use something like this:

```
$.get('myfile.php?b=' + b, function (data) { 
    /* Handle any data that was returned by HTTP Request */ 
});
```

Then in php you can access it by using:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["b"]))
    echo 'b: ' . $_GET["b"]
?>
```

You could also try using a HTTP POST request to send variable just like a form would in http, which can be done by:

```
$.post("myfile.php", { b: {myvarname} },
  function(data){
    /* Handle any data that was returned by HTTP Request */
});
```

Then in php you access it by using:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["b"]))
    echo 'b: ' . $_POST["b"]
?>
```

You can read more at http://docs.jquery.com/Post

**Just be aware of Bots that follow links and remember to do sanity checks on all variables passed to you.**

**Haven't tested the code, please correct me if you spot errors**

Comment: Thanks for your gr8 help. really appreciated. Is it a problem if I use Jquery, PHP and HTMl in the same file. I think thats the problm am not able to access it. Please advise.

Comment: Could you explain your situation a bit more ? Are you using one .php file that outputs the html and javascript and then trying to call the same file to perform the operations? If so you could easily check if the file was passed a certain variable and then only output what your request would need and not the entire html page.

Comment: Yes I am using a single file here. I have a table, and when user click on a cell I am throwing a textbox(temporary) and read the value(thats my "b"), and pass that value back to the PHP to update the table cell. I am not able to paste my full code otherwise I would have done here. Please let me know if you need full code to see, I will paste it at the top.

Comment: Ok just need to know what exactly does not work? Is the request failing? Did you update your JavaScript to give the key and values? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I updated javascript with exact get, and also my PHP with proper access. if(isset($_GET["b"]))  { echo "hello"; echo 'b: ' . $_GET["b"]; } it doesn't go inside this if at all.

Comment: Strange... And are you sure the url is myfile.php?b=test ? Maybe try typing in the url in your browser and just see what it does?

Comment: Debug time.... Check if you can alert the variable before trying to send it. So you can check if you actually get the variable. Then I can't see where you check for the item and remember you can listen for the variable and then call exit to stop further output of all the html to the user.

Comment: Alert works fine. I checked everything. I am lost now. Anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok try this if you create a file with a .php and with <?php if(isset($_POST["b"])) echo 'b: ' . $_POST["b"]; ?> as the content and try to access it from the url and see if you get something, can't think of anythin more you try ...